# Is "int &temperature" the same as "int& temperature" in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, pass-by-reference, declaration, function-prototypes

I am doing an assignment for a CS class and they want me to make a prototype for this:

```
void myFunction(double pressure, int &temperature, double &volume){
     ...
}
```

But I understand it should be more like this:

```
void myFunction(double pressure, int& temperature, double& volume){
     ...
}
```

Can anyone tell me if there's something tricky here? Is `int &temperature` the same as `int& temperature` when it comes to compiling?

Comment: Short answer: yes.  Unless there are parenthesis that specify otherwise, the spacing means the same thing on either side of the `&` and `*` modifiers.

Comment: I prefer the second format, as `int &a, b;` is more consistent with how the compiler treats the code that `int& a, b;`.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes, they are the same.  Unless there are parenthesis that specify otherwise, the spacing means the same thing on either side of the `&` and `*` modifiers.  After that it is a code styling option that is mostly up to you.

Comment: Using the idiom "int& reference" may more clearly convey that reference is an "int&" (int reference), but they are the same.

Comment: Hey! You just copied that guy's comment!... oh wait, sorry. :P

Comment: @MarkGarcia: :-) I realized that it was a decent answer, so I decided to post it.

Answer (score 3):

They are exactly the same.  Whitespace between tokens is (mostly) irrelevent.

Answer (score 3):

When using `*` and `&`, white spaces don't matter, so:

```
int &temperature
```

is equivalent to:

```
int& temperature
```

and also to:

```
int & temperature
```

And which one you will use is just a matter of taste. I personally prefer the second one since the type of `temperature` is `int&`, i.e. I find it more reasonable to keep it together with type. However, I'm pretty sure that some people might give reasonable arguments to explain why they prefer another one as well.

White spaces are however important to maintain your code clean & easy to read. Although, you always encounter some nasty stuff like `if (a --> 3)` from time to time :)